# Implementing common functionality across different TableQuery[T]

Tags: scala, slick

Looking for some guidance on whether the following is possible:

I have the following utility function that I have created specifically for one of my classes (`ContentCollectionFilter`):

```scala
    def updateFilters(updatedFilters: List[ContentCollectionFilter]) = {
      DBIO.sequence(updatedFilters.map { 
        theFilter => {
          TableQuery[ContentCollectionFilterTable].filter(_.id === filter.id.toString()).update(theFilter)
        }
      })
    }
```

My `ContentCollectionFilter` is defined as such:

```scala
final case class ContentCollectionFilter(
        id:           UUID,
        collectionId: UUID,
        filterType:   CollectionFilterType,
        filterValue:  String
)
```

I'd really like to make this function generic to any class that has an `id` field.

I should be able to just create a Trait called `ModelWithId`, have my `ContentCollectionFilter` extend it and then pass that into a more generic function like so:

`def updateIt(toUpdate: List[ModelWithId])`

However I need to also generalize:

1. Which `TableQuery[...]` to use inside the function (implicit lookup?)
2. The parameter type that is passed to TableQuery's `update(...)` as I don't think it would accept a parameter of type `ModelWithId`, it would need to be the class specific to the `ContentCollectionFilterTable`

For reference, `ContentCollectionFilterTable` is defined as so:

```scala
class ContentCollectionFilterTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ContentCollectionFilter] (tag, "collection_filter") { ... }
```

**P.S.** I am using Slick `3.3.3` with Scala `2.13.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out as follows:

Created a `ModelWithId` trait..

```scala
trait ModelWithId {
  def id: UUID
}
```

and have `ContentCollectionFilter` extend it:

```scala
final case class ContentCollectionFilter extends (
        override val id:  UUID,
           collectionId:  UUID,
             filterType:  CollectionFilterType,
            filterValue:  String
) extends ModelWithId
```

Created a `TableWithId` abstract class:

```scala
abstract class TableWithId[T](tag: Tag, tableName: String) extends Table[T] (tag, tableName) {

  def id: Rep[String]

}
```

Created a `TableWithIdOps` trait:

```scala
trait TableWithIdOps[T <: TableWithId[E], E <: ModelWithId] {
  def query: TableQuery[T]
  def insert(insertObj:E) = {
    query += insertObj
  }
  
  def update(updateObj:E) = {
    query.filter(_.id === updateObj.id.toString).update(updateObj)
  }

}
```

Created a `ContentCollectionFilterTable` object:

```
object ContentCollectionFilterTable extends TableWithIdOps[ContentCollectionFilterTable, ContentCollectionFilter] {
  override def query = TableQuery[ContentCollectionFilterTable]
}
```

Changed my existing `ContentCollectionFilterTable` trait to extend `TableWithId`:

```scala
class ContentCollectionFilterTable(tag: Tag) extends TableWithId[ContentCollectionFilter] (tag, "collection_filter") {
  override def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def collectionId = column[String]("collection_id")
  def filterType = column[CollectionFilterType]("filter_type")
  def filterValue = column[String]("filter_value")  
  //...
}
```

Usage:

```scala
def updateContentCollection(contentCollectionFilter: ContentCollectionFilter) = {
  val action = ContentCollectionTableFilter.update(contentCollectionFilter)
  Await.result(getDatabase.run(action), Duration.Inf)
}
```